# Missing CRS from QGIS 2.18.16

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, ogr, epsg

I have installed QGIS 2.18.16 under Linux Mint 18.3.

Opening QGIS about, I read that QGIS is compiled against GDAL/OGR 1.11.3, while from Synaptic I read gdal-data as version 2.2.2.

The problem that I encounter is that I need to use a certain CRS (in particular EPSG:6875) and this is not present in the list of available CRS, while reading online it seems that it is usually available.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create it yourself.

Settings> Custom CRS...

Name:
6875 - RDN2008 / Italy zone

Parameters:

`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=0.9985000000000001 +x_0=7000000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

Answer (score 1):

If your QGIS is compiled against GDAL 1.11.3, you have added the `qgis.org/debian xenial` [repo](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu).

If you want the latest GDAL, you have to add the `ubuntugis-unstable` [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/?field.series_filter=xenial), and switch to the `qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial` repo.

Be sure to remove **and purge** all packages before re-installing, and test with `apt-cache policy gdal` and `qgis` to see what you can get.

---

**UPDATE**

qgis.org now has QGIS 3.0.0 as current and QGIS 2.18.17 as ltr, so you have to switch to the ltr repo if you want to stay on QGIS 2.18.